# How to delete an image from Graphics

Tags: c#, image, graphics

Suppose I use DrawImage a few times to draw a bunch of images.

`e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, destRect);`

How can I delete a specific image from the Graphics paper that I drew it on?
Is there a specific function I can use for deletion?

I have tried `dispose` and `Rectangle.Empty`, but they don't actually delete the image I already drew on the paper.

Comment: By delete, do you mean redraw what was there before, or just cover with a solid color? Once you draw something onto the Graphics, whatever was underneath it is gone.

Comment: Well I was looking for a way to remove the rectangle. I am trying to implement a game breakout game where I have a ball, paddle, and a bunch of bricks. Once the ball hits a brick, the brick (rectangle) should be removed. I already have the ball bouncing off the bricks, and am trying to figure out a way to permanently remove each brick rect so the ball will not rebound off empty space.

Comment: There is no concept of "removed" with a `Graphics` object. You have to redraw whatever the background behind the brick was from some other source.

Comment: it's just a 'piece of paper', no objects there to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no concept of "delete an object" in GDI+ Graphics. You have to redraw the the entire client area in every frame. You should keep a list of objects and their states in memory and redraw the entire surface in every frame. Beware though, this can lead to flickers and not-so-smooth user experience. Here are a few tips to avoid these:

1. Make sure your Form or UserControl has its `DoubleBuffered` property set to True. This will result in a far smoother animation than otherwise.
2. NEVER EVER call `CreateGraphics()` to get a reference to the Graphics object in your drawing loop. Update your list of objects and states in your loop and then call `Invalidate()` on your Control/Form and do the drawing process in `Paint` event.
3. One overload of `Invalidate()` allows you to specify the rectangle that needs to be invalidated (redrawn). You can pass a "safe" rectangle around your bouncing ball's current position (say 20 pixels wider/taller than the ball size) as agrument and then draw only that portion in your `Paint` event.
4. To further increase performance you can keep auxilary information such as scores, player names etc. outside the actual "game board" and use normal labels/textboxes for them instead of drawing.

Comment: What's your suggestion for balls hitting the bricks? Would you use Rectangle.Empty and use DrawImage again ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. Do you mean how to check for a hit-test? That is as simple as taking the intersection (`Rectangle.IntersectsWith()`) of the brick rectangle and the ball rectangle.

Comment: Yeah I currently use intersects with. But I don't see any other option for removing bricks other than the procedure below.

Comment: You could keep a bool property in your brick class called `Visible` or something and turn it to `False` once upon hit. Then in your `Paint` code, you could draw only those bricks that are Visible. You could use the same property in hit test too in addition to `IntersectsWith()`.

Answer (score 1):

krikara, what you should do is:

1. Keep track of all the bricks in a list
2. When the ball hits a brick, remove that brick from the list

Every frame, you must redraw everything from scratch. This includes the ball, the paddle and the list of bricks (and whatever else you need, like score, etc.)

Hope this clears up whatever confusion you had.